# Difference Between 'd' and 'dd/MM/yyyy' Formats

Tags: c#, datetime

What is difference between -

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date, provider, 
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault).Date;
return dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

and

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date, provider, 
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault).Date;
return dt.ToString("d");
```

Comment: well, have you run them to compare the output? Or tried reading the documentation about what "d" does?

Comment: one is localized `d` and one is hard coded.

Comment: `d` for me would be `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: For reference: [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) (there are even examples of multiple cultures!)

Comment: @DanielA.White This is not quite the case; `d` is a pre-defined format; `dd/MM/yyyy` is a custom-defined format.

Answer (score 1):

***d***: This is a standard (or pre-defined) format for `DateTime` objects. For example, in the US, utilizing `.ToString("d")` will return a date in `M/d/yyyy` format.

***dd/MM/yyyy***: This is a custom (or user-defined) format for `DateTime` objects. For example, this allows you to specify exactly how the `DateTime` object should be represented as a string:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, d MMM yyyy gg @ HH:mm:ss tt"));
```

The code above outputs the following result:

> Monday, 6 AUG 2018 A.D. @ 15:41:13 P.M.

***Direct Answer***

If you were to put the following code into a console application and execute it, you can clearly see the difference between `d` and `dd/MM/yyyy`:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d"));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

The output is as follows:

> d: 8/6/2018
>
> dd/MM/yyyy: 06/08/2018

As you can see, `d` results in a format of `M/d/yyyy`; with your second supplied option you have clearly specified a double digit day, then a double digit month, then a quad digit year.

Please refer to the [Standard Date/Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) and [Custom Date/Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) charts for examples and descriptions.